# MVC 5 select dropdown no longer getting populated by jquery after changing the styling using a plugin

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

I've just implemented [bootstrap-select](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/) into my project, but I'm experiencing an issue with it.  In my project there are dropdown menus for departments and locations.  The location list is populated based on the selection of the department dropdown.  After adding the `selectpicker` class to the location dropdown, it no longer gets populated with data.  I'm guessing this plugin changes the dropdown in some way that is causing this to happen.

**Javascript:**

```
$(function () {
    $("#SelectedDepartment").change(function () {
        var self = $(this);
        var items="";
        $.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetLocations","Incident")/" + self.val(),
        function(data){
            $.each(data,function(index,item){
                items += "<option value='" + item.Value + "'>" + item.Text + "</option>";
            });
            $("#SelectedLocation").html(items);
        });
    });
});
```

**View:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        Incident department/location:
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Departments, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedDepartment,
                                new SelectList(Model.Departments, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "selectpicker", @title = "Select a Department"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Departments, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Locations, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedLocation,
                                new SelectList(Model.Locations, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "", @title = "Select a Location" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Locations, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use this :

```
$('#SelectedLocation').selectpicker('refresh');
```